# How to carry a scientific poster as hand luggage?

Tags: conference, travel

Sometimes I have to present at different conferences. Usually I print the poster at the print office at home and cary the poster with me to the conference. With the more and strict luggage rules, it is not always allowed to carry the usual chunky poster cylinders on board.

As I like to travel light, this sometimes is a problem. One solution would be to look for a print shop at the destination (eg. [Paris](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10801/where-to-print-science-posters-in-paris) or [Berlin](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18037/can-i-print-a-science-poster-in-berlin-within-one-day)).

But then again, you also want to bring back the poster with you.

So my question, how can I bring a a1/a2 poster with me as carry-on luggage?